# Returning a dataobject from promise.success function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, typescript, promise

I'm making an AJAX request and I'm having trouble processing the promise response. In the example the AJAX request is made inside the function not shown but called' `requestOriginalDataFromAjax()`.

In "promise" form it is unusable and needs to be converted to a regular data object with a `promise.success` function. But passing data OUT of the `promise.success` function is where I run into trouble. The returned data always comes back `undefined`.

Here is an example:

```
private convertPromise(){

      let requestedData:any = this.requestOriginalDataFromAjax();

      let promise:any = requestedData;

      promise.success(function (data) {
          console.log("data inside my converter: ");
          console.log(data);
          return data;
      });
}

private needToDoSomethingWithTheDataNow(){

      let convertedData:any = this.convertPromise();

      console.log("returned data: ");
      console.log(convertedData);
}
```

HERE is the console output:

```
data inside my converter:
full_data_object: ["blah":"blah"]

returned data:
undefined
```

I know this question has been asked in the past but after all my research and reading I still can't understand based on those previous examples.

Comment: The return statement on the promise is returning inside the lambda. The `convertPromise` function is not returning anything, thus undefined.

Comment: @JuanmaSerrano I saved the value to a variable outside the function and attempted to return that, and it was still undefined. what would the syntax look like?

Answer (score 0):

You need to return the promise in the convertPromise function and then consume it correctly in the caller:

```
private convertPromise(){

  let requestedData:any = this.requestOriginalDataFromAjax();

  let promise:any = requestedData;

  promise.success(function (data) {
      console.log("data inside my converter: ");
      console.log(data);
      return data;
  });

  return promise;
```

}

private needToDoSomethingWithTheDataNow(){

```
  let convertedDataPromise:any = this.convertPromise();

  convertedDataPromise.success((function(convertedData) {
    console.log("returned data: ");
    console.log(convertedData);
  });
```

}

Comment: But this is redundant. The purpose of the converter is only to make the promise a normal data object and pass it around in that form. Is that possible?

Comment: Ah I see, no. If you are dealing with promises then everything must be within one. You could call a callback from within a promise instead if that helps. But really once you go down the route of promises then everything needs to be within the .then / .success / .error logic

Comment: Thanks that answers everything!